# Magento 2 discards all session parameters

Tags: php, magento, session, magento2

I've written a magento controller which stores some filter information inside the customer session.

According to the magento 2 documentation I use dependency injection to let magento generate the session object for me:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session
 */
protected $_filterSession;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $filterSession
 */
public function __construct( \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $filterSession)
{
    $this->_filterSession = $filterSession;
}
```

The injection process is working quite well. I'm able to access the session, store a variable in it and return it on a further invocation.

But magento seems to discard the whole session information from time to time. I cannot exactly identify the moment magento discards the information, it seems kind of random.

Here is the code:

```
$this->_filterSession->setFrequency($frequency);
$frequency = $this->_filterSession->getFrequency();
```

I tried out different session scopes but the behaviour is the same.

After many attempts I tried to use the PHP-session to store the information, but even this session was discarded from time to time.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or what could be the reason for this weird behaviour. Does anybody else have a similar problem or an idea whats the reason?

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when the browser loses session cookies. You should check if domain name changes during the session when the variables are lost. Or with a different browser. Might be some misbehaving browser plugin. Or some Magento extension. Many Mageno 2 extensions currently are poorly written.

Comment: I think you are right. I could not identify which extension does this but since also session parameters are lost that used from magento itself, there has to be an erroneous extension.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem using PHP. I had set  `session.referer_check`. So, when a user was coming from an external page, the session was lost. If this is your problem, simply `ini_set('session.referer_check', '');`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the phenomina also appears when I navigate on the same page inside the same tab. Checked it out anyways. Didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution to the problem itself, but avoided it.

For those who also encounter the problem, here is my bandaid fix:

I introduced a new cookie

```
public function getFrequency()
{
    $frequency = $this->_cookieManager->getCookie(self::FREQUENCY_SESSION_KEY);


    if( !isset( $frequency ) )
    {
        $frequency = self::FREQUENCY_DEFAULT_VALUE;
    }

    return $frequency;
}

public function setFrequency( $frequency )
{
    $metadata = $this->_cookieMetadataFactory
        ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
        ->setPath($this->_sessionManager->getCookiePath())
        ->setDomain($this->_sessionManager->getCookieDomain());

    $this->_cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
        self::FREQUENCY_SESSION_KEY,
        $frequency,
        $metadata
    );
}
```

for further details I recommend you to look at this [thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100136/how-to-add-cookie-magento-2).

Regards, Thomas